# How to select and crop an image in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my rails app I am giving an option to upload an image to set his/her profile picture. I want to give an option to customise the picture at UI side and save it.

So that user can upload any size photos and he can select any part of the image and crop it.

How do I achieve this requirement? Currently I am using paperclip gem.

**Any javascript plugin is available?**

**Any other gem is available?**

**Is it possible with paperclip gem also?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use this Plugin -- http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html or actually you're looking for like this kind of

http://runnable.com/UnsVs_ZiUaV6AAAY/how-to-crop-images-with-paperclip-for-ruby-on-rails

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast